# Date SOAP webservice

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap

I'm having a problem sending a java.util.Date object from my C# client to my java webserver.
When I am calling a WebMethod with a Date WebParam it works. But if I am calling a WebMethod with a custom object that has a Date as WebParam it's always null.

So, this works:

```
@WebMethod(operationName="thisWorks")
public void thisWorks(@WebParam(name="from")Date from)
{
    System.out.println(from); //prints the value of the date
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
class MyObj { java.util.Date getMyDate(); }

@WebMethod(operationName="thisDoesntWork")
public void thisDoesntWork(@WebParam(name="myObj")MyObj myObj)
{
    System.out.println(myObj.getMyDate()); //prints null
}
```

Client:

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
client.thisWorks(DateTime.Now);
myObj o = new myObj();
o.myDate = DateTime.Now;
client.thisDoesntWork(o);
```

Comment: use http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ or http://devolutions.net/products/HTTP-Spy-Net.aspx to debug what is sent between your server and your client

Comment: You're showing the Java side, care to share your C# client code?

Comment: you show `class MyObj { java.util.Date getMyDate(); }` on the server-side while on the client-side you show a field/property `myDate` - that doesn't match at all IMO!

Comment: myObj is generated from the wsdl. The MyObj class on the server has a field myDate with a getter and setter. When I give this class an int member it works. But with date it doesnt

Comment: The wsdl generates an extra field for the myDate: "bool myDateSpecified". When I set this to true, it works. This is weird, cause when I would have an int field instead of date I also get a specified field for it, but now I dont have to set the specified field for it to work.

Comment: Please add an answer below instead of adding "solved" to the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wsdl generates an extra field for the myDate: "bool myDateSpecified". When I set this to true, it works. This is weird, cause when I would have an int field instead of date I also get a specified field for it, but now I dont have to set the specified field for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be the .Net XML Serializer. I did rewrite my code in Java and it works beautifully.

I can think in a way to workaround the `{!variable}Specified = true;` sentence:

Move the entire declaration of the object to a separated namespace. So, everytime you update the WSDL your code does not get overwritten.

And do not use the `System.Nullable<bool>` in the property declaration, use `bool` or `DateTime` or `Double`. Get the point?